# QTimer как опросить состояние таймеров?

Tags: qt

QTimer  как опросить состояние таймеров ??

**Сейчас :**

создаю в mainwindow.h

```
public:
      ...
      QTimer  *timer[3];
      ...
```

объявляю в mainwindow.сpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ...

    timer[0] = new QTimer(this);
    timer[1] = new QTimer(this);
    timer[2] = new QTimer(this);
    timer[3] = new QTimer(this);

    connect(timer[0],SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(izmenenie_0()));
    connect(timer[1],SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(izmenenie_1()));
    connect(timer[2],SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(izmenenie_2()));
    connect(timer[3],SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(izmenenie_3()));

    timer[0]->start(1000);
    timer[1]->start(1200);
    timer[2]->start(1300);
    timer[3]->start(1700);
}
```

Хотелось бы избавиться от такого количества функций (izmenenie_0, izmenenie_1, izmenenie_2, izmenenie_3).
А оставить только одну в которой будет проверяться какой из таймеров её вызвал (вызвать timerId() возможно), но я это не умею и даже не представляю как это написать.

**Хотелось бы:**

```
    connect(timer[0],SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(izmenenie()));
    connect(timer[1],SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(izmenenie()));
    connect(timer[2],SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(izmenenie()));
    connect(timer[3],SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(izmenenie()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [`QObject *QObject::sender() const`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender), получите в слоте указатель на `QObject`, отправивший сигнал. А там уже думайте дальше как наладить учет и разбирательство с таймерами.

Answer (score 0):

К примеру через sender`a или через лямбду

mainwindow.h

....

```
    #define NUM_TIMERS 10
    QTimer *_timers[NUM_TIMERS];
private slots:
    void slotTimerTimeout();
```

....

mainwindow.cpp

....

```
    ui->setupUi(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TIMERS; ++i) {
        QTimer *pTimer = new QTimer;
        _timers[i]=pTimer;
        //Вариант 1 (без лямбды) закомментировать
        connect(pTimer,&QTimer::timeout,this,&MainWindow::slotTimerTimeout);
        //Вариант 2 (с лямбдой) раскомментировать
//        connect(pTimer,&QTimer::timeout,this,[i,pTimer](){
//            qDebug() << QStringLiteral("Timer %1 with interval %2.").arg(i).arg(pTimer->interval());
//        });
        pTimer->start((i+1)*300);
    }
```

....

```
void MainWindow::slotTimerTimeout()
{
    QTimer *castTimer = static_cast<QTimer*>(sender());
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TIMERS; ++i) {
        if(castTimer==_timers[i])
        {
            qDebug() << QStringLiteral("Timer %1 with interval %2.").arg(i).arg(castTimer->interval());
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

...

PS И не забудь удалить все таймера в деструкторе.